# Android - Lock Screen via App and if user unlocks , system should ask for password

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am developing an App in which I need to lock screen than if user unlocks, it should ask for password...
Help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you basically need is a way to make sure that the user has a password set for their lock screen. There's no clean way of doing this. No formal API. If you're willing to risk a hack, you can try this. I cobbled it together some code I found on this [site](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/com/android/internal/widget/LockPatternUtils.java#LockPatternUtils.0sLockPasswordFilename).

```
boolean hasPasswordOnLockScreen(){
  String sLockPasswordFilename = 
    android.os.Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
    "/system/password.key";
  try {
        // Check if we can read a byte from the file
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "r");
        raf.readByte();
        raf.close();
        return true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        return false;
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note that this is a hack and has the potential to not work in the future is the path and file name of the password file changes.

Comment: i can lock phone using my app...but as per OS, is there any way where my app will request user to enter password as soon as user tries to unlock it? i am kind of stuck here